Global variables not working in Woocommerce thank you page
Error_log returns the expected value, but formatted_recurring_amount is returning the default value. Is the code executing in the wrong order, or is there something wrong with my code?
<?php
global $recurring_amount;
$recurring_amount = 1; // Initialize with a default value

add_filter('woocommerce_subscription_price_string', function($subscription_string, $subscription_details) {
    global $recurring_amount;
    $recurring_amount = $subscription_details['recurring_amount'];

    error_log('Recurring Amount: ' . $recurring_amount);

    return $subscription_string;
}, 10, 2);

add_filter('woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'add_recurring_row_to_totals', 10, 2);

function add_recurring_row_to_totals($total_rows, $order) {
    global $recurring_amount;

    $formatted_recurring_amount = isset($recurring_amount) ? wc_price($recurring_amount) : wc_price(0);

    $total_rows['recurring_amount'] = array(
        'label' => __('Recurring Amount:', 'woocommerce'),
        'value' => $formatted_recurring_amount,
    );

    return $total_rows;
}

Trying to pass the subscription amount from the Woocommerce Subscriptions plugin to the Woocommerce thank you (order-received) page using filter hooks.

Please provide me an example or a screenshot where this issue coming so can provide a better solution. Thanks
